# python mechanize yahoo mail

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to use python / mechanize to login to yahoo mail. I am new to mechanize, but is there This is what I have, why is it saying no form named "login"

```
import mechanize

url = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=us&.src=ym"
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="login")
br.close()
```

Screen shot below of yahoo mail website. Thanks

[image]

Comment: The **`input`** name is `login`, you have to find the **`form`** tag and get it's `name`. It should be somewhere above those `input`s.

Comment: great, then how do I pick the field with in the form

Comment: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the form's names with

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form.name
```

Since there are probably only a few forms on this page, the name should be obvious.  Otherwise, you can get the form id similarly; you should be able to get it with

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

or `br.select_form(nr=1)`

since some forms may not have a name.

Comment: Then of course you still need to insert your data into the two fields and submit the form.